# i get trouble finding my fluid, i'm a beginner

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, fluid-simulation

i was following this tutorial on youtube https://youtu.be/3lvpNM1DrYU and i'm having trouble finding my fluid options, you may see it on 5:58 in the link i shared

the picture bellow is how my settings look like.

is there any possible way to fix mine? :(

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). The tutorial is using the old fluid system. You'll need Blender 2.81 to follow it precisely: https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.81/

Comment: hi, oh i understood, that's why mine isn't the same as the tutorial! thank you so much btw!